# Modifying the values of levels in multiindex

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I'm trying to consolidate  a dataframe with multiple rows with the same state, but different counties.  The level values for the 'Province/State' have the county names and the 2 letter state code as one string.  I have figured out the regex to parse the names how I want, I just don't know how to modify the levels.

Eventually I will sum all the column data for each state as one value for each state, eliminating the county granularity.

I want to edit the 'Province/State' level values from:

```
['Westchester County, NY',
 'King County, WA',
 'Diamond Princess',
 'Santa Clara County, CA',
 'Snohomish County, WA',
 'Grand Princess',
 'New York County, NY',
 'Nassau County, NY',
 'Los Angeles, CA',
 'Contra Costa County, CA',
 'San Francisco County, CA',
 'Washington County, OR',
 'Suffolk County, MA',
 'Middlesex County, MA',
 'Cook County, IL']
```

To:

```
['New York',
 'Washington',
 'Diamond Princess',
 'California',
 'Washington',
 'Grand Princess',
 'New York',
 'New York',
 'California',
 'California',
 'California',
 'Oregon',
 'Massachusetts',
 'Massachusetts',
 'Illinois']
```

Here is the code to create my test dataframe:

```
nam=['DataType', 'Country/Region', 'Province/State', 'Lat', 'Long']

cols=['3/4/20', '3/5/20', '3/6/20', '3/7/20', '3/8/20', '3/9/20', '3/10/20',
       '3/11/20', '3/12/20', '3/13/20']
dat = np.array([[10, 18, 19, 57, 83, 98,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [31, 51, 58, 71, 83, 83,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 46, 46, 46, 46],
       [11, 20, 20, 32, 38, 38,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 8, 18, 19, 27, 31, 31,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21],
       [ 1,  4, 11, 11, 12, 19,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  1,  4,  5, 17,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 7, 11, 13, 14, 14, 14,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  3,  3,  9,  9,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  2,  2,  9,  9,  9,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  3,  8,  8,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  3,  3,  8,  8,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  7,  7,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 4,  5,  5,  6,  7,  7,  0,  0,  0,  0]])

tups = [('Confirmed', 'US', 'Westchester County, NY', 41.122, -73.7949),
 ('Confirmed', 'US', 'King County, WA', 47.6062, -122.3321),
 ('Confirmed', 'US', 'Diamond Princess', 35.4437, 139.638),
 ('Confirmed', 'US', 'Santa Clara County, CA', 37.3541, -121.9552),
 ('Confirmed', 'US', 'Snohomish County, WA', 48.033, -121.8339),
 ('Confirmed', 'US', 'Grand Princess', 37.6489, -122.6655),
 ('Confirmed', 'US', 'New York County, NY', 40.7128, -74.006),
 ('Confirmed', 'US', 'Nassau County, NY', 40.6546, -73.5594),
 ('Confirmed', 'US', 'Los Angeles, CA', 34.0522, -118.2437),
 ('Confirmed', 'US', 'Contra Costa County, CA', 37.8534, -121.9018),
 ('Confirmed', 'US', 'San Francisco County, CA', 37.7749, -122.4194),
 ('Confirmed', 'US', 'Washington County, OR', 45.547, -123.1386),
 ('Confirmed', 'US', 'Suffolk County, MA', 42.3601, -71.0589),
 ('Confirmed', 'US', 'Middlesex County, MA', 42.4672, -71.2874),
 ('Confirmed', 'US', 'Cook County, IL', 41.7377, -87.6976)]

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tups)
samp = pd.DataFrame(data = dat,columns = cols,index=idx)                    
samp.index.names=nam
```

Here is the code I'm using to parse the names:

```
state_code = {
        'CA': 'California',
        'IL': 'Illinois',
        'MA': 'Massachusetts',
        'NY': 'New York',
        'OR': 'Oregon',
        'WA': 'Washington',   }


states = samp.index.get_level_values('Province/State')

p = re.compile(r"[A-Z]{2}")
q = re.compile(r"(\w+ *\w*)")

s1 = [state_code[p.search(ss).group()] if p.search(ss) != None else q.search(ss).group() for ss in states]

s1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define s1 as dict rather than list. 
Then you just get the index level 'Province/State' out and you put it back in.

```
s1 = {ss :state_code[p.search(ss).group()] if p.search(ss) != None else q.search(ss).group() for ss in states}

orig_order = samp.index.names
samp = samp.reset_index(level=2)
samp['Province/State'] = samp['Province/State'].map(lambda x: s1[x])
samp = samp.set_index(['Province/State'], append=True)
samp = samp.reorder_levels(orig_order, axis=0)
```

Comment: I had tried various methods to modify the levels directly, but it looks like I had to reset the index and modify the column.  Thanks!